# Target object for this command has incorrect format

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain-controller, import, organizational-unit

I'm doing some 70-410 training and this script that I'm trying to run that I made keeps on failing due to an error that I receive that I stated in the topic. doesanyone see anything wrong in this:

```
dsadd OU ou=IL,dc=sawahcompany,dc=com
dsadd OU "ou=Chicago,ou=IL,dc=sawahcompany,dc=com"
dsadd OU "ou=Schaumburg,ou=IL,dc=sawahcompany,dc=com"
dsadd OU "Chicago Admins,ou=Chicago,ou=IL,dc=sawahcompany,dc=com"
dsadd OU "User Accounts,ou=Chicago Admins,ou=Chicago,ou=IL,dc=sawahcompany,dc=com"
dsadd OU "Computer Accounts,ou=Chicago Admins,ou=Chicago,ou=IL,dc=sawahcompany,dc=com"
dsadd OU "Chicago Desktops,ou=Chicago,ou=IL,dc=sawahcompany,dc=com"
dsadd OU "Chicago Laptops,ou=Chicago,ou=IL,dc=sawahcompany,dc=com"
dsadd ou "Chicago Servers,ou=Chicago,ou=IL,dc=sawahcompany,dc=com"
dsadd ou "Chicago Users,ou=Chicago,ou=IL,dc=sawahcompany,dc=com"
dsadd ou "Schaumburg Admins,ou=Schaumburg,ou=IL,dc=sawahcompany,dc=com"
dsadd ou "Schaumburg Desktops,ou=Schaumburg,ou=IL,dc=sawahcompany,dc=com"
dsadd ou "Schaumburg Laptops,ou=Schaumburg,ou=IL,dc=sawahcompany,dc=com"
dsadd ou "Schaumburg Servers,ou=Schaumburg,ou=IL,dc=sawahcompany,dc=com"
dsadd ou "Schaumburg Users,ou=Schaumburg,ou=IL,dc=sawahcompany,dc=com"
pause
```

Answer (score 3):

The first container names lack the container type from your third statement on down to the bottom, and you don't have the first one quoted (for consistency). For example, it should be "ou=Chicago Admins,ou=Chicago,ou=IL,dc=sawahcompany,dc=com".

Comment: Sorrry man, I understand what you're saying but can you share exactly which third OU you are referring to?

Comment: All of the OU's below Schaumburg lack the "ou=" part of the Distinguished Name for the first OU in the DN. For example, it should be "ou=Chicago Admins,ou=Chicago,ou=IL,dc=sawahcompany,dc=com".

Comment: All of the statements, that is. I edited my answer to clarify.